# Can I use auditd on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: security

[auditd](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/) is a kernel demon that can snoop on users using your server.  Can it be used on a Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to. The package exists in the RPi repo, but after installing, I can't add any rules to it. It always says:

```
Error sending add rule data request (Invalid argument)
```

I read about this on other forums, and this seems to be a kernel related problem. 
Or

```
Error detecting machine type
```

Even if I specify it with "-F arch=armv6l".
So it seems, you can't, until these're fixed.